# OpenCV 3.1.0 : How to use BackgroundSubtractorMOG class

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have OpenCV 3.1.0 installed. 
I want to use BackgroundSubtractorMOG so in my file i have these includes:

```
//opencv
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>

//C
#include <stdio.h>
//C++
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
```

I declare a pointer to a class of this type:

```
Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG> pMOG;
```

And I initialize the pointer like this:

```
pMOG = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG();
```

When I try to compile I get this:

```
/home/edd/Desktop/compvis/FML.cpp:19:5: error: ‘BackgroundSubtractorMOG’ was not declared in this scope
 Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG> pMOG; //MOG2 Background subtractor
     ^
/home/edd/Desktop/compvis/FML.cpp:19:28: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG> pMOG; //MOG2 Background subtractor
                            ^
/home/edd/Desktop/compvis/FML.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/edd/Desktop/compvis/FML.cpp:29:42: error: ‘createBackgroundSubtractorMOG’ was not declared in this scope
     pMOG = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG(); //MOG approach
                                          ^
```

I tried to look in the documentation. I couldn't figure out what header to include. I couldn't figure out how to instantiate an instance of the class correctly.

What do ?

Comment: The info here is not helpful: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/da7/classcv_1_1bgsegm_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG.html

Comment: try [offical tutorial code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/video/bg_sub.cpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you've posted, I don't see any statement regarding namespaces. (e.g. `using namespace cv` in your preamble). Otherwise, you have to preface OpenCV code with `cv::` (e.g. `cv::Mat frame` to declare a Mat object).

EDIT:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/bgsegm.hpp"
...
cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractor> mog = cv::bgsegm::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG();
...
```

And by using the namespace:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/bgsegm.hpp"

using namespace cv
...
Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> mog = bgsegm::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG();
...
```

Hope this helps,
MJ

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It seems I missed this part.

Comment: @edd No problem. Glad I could help!